# Special occasions where various Chassidim don't say Tachanun

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism, tachanun

Various Chassidim have different customs regarding special occasions where they don't say Tachanun.

[I know this because sometimes I daven in a Vishnitz shule and, upon asking why they didn't say Tachanun one Chassid answered that it was a special day for Vishnitz
(I forgot what exactly... maybe a Yartzeit of a Rebbe)]

For instance Chabad chassidim don't say Tachanun on a day where one of the Chabad Rebbeim
was released from prison. (= Yom HaGeulah)
[see [Sefer HaMinhagim](https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/4160951) p16, [Hayom Yom 19th Kislev](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6009/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Kislev-19.htm), [12th Tamuz](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5824/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Tamuz-12-Festival-of-Liberation.htm) and [13th Tamuz](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5825/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Tamuz-13-Festival-of-Liberation.htm) (search for the word 'Tachanun')]

What special days/occasions do other branches of Chasiddim have on which they don't say Tachanun?

Comment: I remember hearing of a new shull in Israel were many of the congregants were Chassidim and were not going to say tachanun, but many others were not and were going to. In order to avoid the conflict the Rabbi of the shull begged a newly married man to daven there on that day so that everyone would not say tachanun and avoid the conflict that could have harmed the new (i.e. it did not have settled minhagim yet) shull. (Yes, I know this doesn't answer the question, it just seemed like an interesting story to share.)

Comment: See the answers to this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2653/3

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask the question the other way?

Comment: You want an exhaustive list?

Comment: @SethJ : An exhaustive list isn't necessary, however if you know of particular klallim which various Chassidim have  regerding not saying Tachanun - that would do. [i.e like the one  I mentioned in my question , or like msh210 pointed out about not saying Tachanun in Mincha.

Comment: On days ending in -y

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Most Chassidic Groups:**<sup>1</sup>

- On the *yahrtzeit* of a rabbi with connection to the group (either a previous rebbe, or someone with substantial influence on the group or that town's inhabitants).
- When their rebbe does, e.g. when his child gets married or is circumcised.
- On days when special joyous events happened to their past rebbes, e.g. they were freed from prison or concentration camp, or a decree affecting them was abolished.

**Zionists**:

- On *Yom HaAtzma'ut*.<sup>3</sup>

**Anti-Zionists:**

- **Do** say *tachanun* on on *Yom HaAtzma'ut*, even if there would be reasons not to say. <sup>a)</sup> <sup>4</sup>

**[*Munkatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munkacs_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29):**<sup>5</sup>

- If there is a circumcision anywhere in that town (common custom is only that synagogue).
- By *Mincha*.<sup>b)</sup>

**[*Satmar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satmar_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29):**

- On Fridays.<sup>4</sup>

**[*Viznitz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizhnitz_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29):**<sup>6</sup>

- On *Erev Rosh Chodesh* if it is after the *molad*.
- Reb Mendel's chassidim by *Mincha*, even though it is always before sunset.<sup>c)</sup>

**[*Zidichov*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zidichov_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29):**<sup>8</sup>

- From *Rosh Chodesh Adar I* until seven days after *Shavuos*.
- Whenever there can be found a reason (e.g. *Mincha*, *Yahrtzeit*,...).

**[*Shotz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotz):**<sup>8</sup>

- By *Mincha*.

---

**Notes:**

a) The current [*Belz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belz_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29)​er rebbe himself steps out of his own synagogue to say *tachanun* alone, if his synagogue omits it by a *bris milah*. This is even though he is the *sandak* and *mohel* and normally would not say *tachanun*, even in a *minyan* other that where the *bris* takes place.<sup>2</sup>

b) [*Lev Tahor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Helbrans#Lev_Tahor) says *tachanun* by *Mincha*, even though they use the *Munkatch*​er *siddur*.<sup>1</sup>

c) Reb Mendel keeps the custom of his father, Reb  Moshele, who abolished *tachanun* by *Mincha*. However, traditionally it **is** said, and so do Reb Mottele's chassidim, and Reb Yisroel is reinstating the old custom for his chassidim.<sup>7</sup>

---

<sub>**Sources:**</sub>

1 Personal experience

2   Heard from Lipa Klein, Montreal, a prominent *Belz*​er chassid who was there

3 Such chassidim

4 *Siddur Yetev Lev*

5 *Siddur Tz'vi Tiferes*

6 *Viznitz*​er *siddur*

7 Montreal's Yisroel-*Viznitz*​er *dayan*

8 Montreal's *Shotz*​er rebbe's son (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizhnitz_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29#Vizhnitz_today) for information about the split within *Viznitz*)

Comment: You deserve a down vote for the comment about Belz. Belz most certainly *does* say Tachanun on Yom HaAtzmaoot. Not only that but because the post Pesach B"HaB cycle many times overlaps with Yom HaAtzmaoot you will find Belzer Chassidim saying selichots on Yom Hatzmaoot. In the Chassidic world Belz is known to be more makpid on Tachnun than others (e.g. Zidatchov) so your comment is waaay off. Please edit your answer

Comment: @eramm Thanks for you comment. I'll ask him again if I understood right. The question intreagued me and I am actively researching the various minhagim. I am now adding Zidichov and Shotz.

Comment: Ziditchov is the most lenient and i believe they never say tachanun at mincha all year round.

Comment: I imagine what your friend witnessed was that there was a bris on Yom Hatzmaoot (since the Rebbe is the defacto sandek/mohel in Belz tachnun is often not said at his minyan) and even though there was a bris the Rebbe said tachnun privately. Bear in mind it's a very rare occasion where the Belzer Rebbe davens in the same room when davening in his personal Beis Medrish so the fact that someone claims to have "seen" is suspect.

Comment: @eramm Regarding Zidichover Mincha, you're right. I intended that to be included in "Whenever...", but I'll edit that. I haven't had a chance to ask yet, but I can reassure you that Lipa Klein does not intend to put Belz or the rebbe in any bad light. After all, he is a staunch Belzer, and contributed a million dollars to build the new beis medrash. Btw, why would the rebbe say tachanun if he was sandek/mohel? That's "against the rules", no?

Comment: emm.. Chabad DO say tachanun on yartzeits of Tzadikim, as opposed to other chasidic groups

Comment: as well as when the Chabad Rebbeim don't say tachanun, the chassidim do, for example zayin adar

Comment: @Efraim Thank you, I wasn't aware of that, and I will change "All" to "Most". I want to add a note too, but can you clarify? Do Chabad say tachanun even on the yahrtzeit of the previous rebbes?

Comment: @NBZ sorry I worded my comment a little unclear, as per Chabad minhag, I'll look up the mekor, but I am pretty sure its in sefer haminhagim, we do say tachanun on yartzeits of all our rebbeim, and I'm pretty sure the Rebbe (MMS) may also have a letter about the connection between saying tachanun and a yartzeit of a tzaddik.

Comment: @eramm You are absolutely right. I misunderstood. Now it is fixed. However, at the time, the Rebbe _did_ daven with the oilom on and off.

Comment: @Efraim, AFAIK, many Lubavitchers have adopted minhagei mishpachat Schneerso(h)n

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt ok, and many haven't...

Answer (score 2):

*Mincha*, for one. It's customary among some *chasidim* to pray *mincha* after sunset, when one does not<sup>[citation needed]</sup> say *tachanun*. Therefore<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, even on the occasion that they pray earlier, some skip *tachanun*.

Comment: Viznitz are careful to daven mincha before shkia, but they never say tachanun by mincha. Munkatch never say tachanun by mincha, it isn't even in their siddur. (Source: the two places I daven most often)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Nusach Sfard ArtScroll US Siddur.  It notes that most people who daven Nusach Sfard don’t say Tachanun during Minchah.  What about on the days the Nesiim brought their Karbanot?  I recall being in Shuls which skipped Tachanun on those days.