# Sources for minhag not saying tachnun on fridays and sundays

Tags: tefilla, tachanun

I prayed in a chasidic shul in europe. They did not say tachnun in sharis of friday and sunday.

I asked them what the reason is and they answered me that in the days close to shabbes tachnun should not be recited.

Is there a halachic source (makor) for this?

The closest answer i could find was this: [Special occasions where various Chassidim don't say Tachanun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/special-occasions-where-various-chassidim-dont-say-tachanun/35099#35099)

It just speaks on friday and there is a source of a siddur but not a halachic sefer.

Comment: I know that Friday Mincha doesn't have Tachnun (I believe due to the generic exemption of no Tachnun on the Mincha before a 'holiday'), but I've never seen that extended to Sunday, or even Friday morning. You're saying that even by Shacharis on those days there is no Tachnun?

Comment: yes. this is what i saw

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36037&st=&pgnum=169&hilite=

Comment: Sunday isn't listed as a day to omit Tachanun by the Tur, anyone quoted in the Batei Yosef, Chadash or Yisrael, by the Shulchan Aruch or its Mapah, the Levush, the Eliya Rabba, the Taz, the Magen Avraham, the Beiur haGra, the Chayei Adam, the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, the Mishna Berura or the Aruch haShulchan. Just FWIW.

Comment: Mi.Yodeya??????

Answer (score 4):

The chasdic source (separate discussion if this is Halchic of Meta Halacha) is quoted in Adir Bmarom by Rabbi Dovid Rabinowitz on page ק he says the minhag in some places is not to say tachnun on Friday or Sunday. I saw in a diffrent sefer that one should eat leftovers from shabbos on sunday because it still has a litile Kedusha of Shabbos.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you tell us a little more about the sefer please?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Friday morning, in Yalkut Yosef Teffilah 2 page 433-434 he quotes many sources:

1. Pri Megadim סימן קלא מש"ז סק"י
2. מתן שכרן של מצות חקירה ח
3. The minhag of the Baal Atzei Chaim, Kedushat Yom tov, Baal Yitav Lev all had the custom of not saying tachanun Friday mornings also.
4. Shu"t Shema Yisrael Siman כ writes that the Arizal says that from Friday morning the Kedusha of Shabbat starts
5. Bnei Yisaschar Bemamarei Hashabbatot מאמר ב

Comment: The pri megadim quoted doesn't say to omit tachanun on friday morning. He just notes that he's not sure why we do say it (since of course we say it since no one ever said not to) given that tosefet shabbat starts on friday afternoon before sunset so the morning should be the time-period prior. Now I'm very skeptical of all your other sources.

Comment: מתן שכרן של מצות חקירה ח is literally another work by the same author as pri megadim making the same comment he made in source 1. How does that count as two separate sources???

Comment: I can't find Shut Shema Yisrael #20 on Hebrewbooks, but no one should trust it says anything about tachanun until someone finds it to verify. Just a claim about when the holiness of shabbat starts (whatever that means) is not an answer.

Comment: Also not sure what שערי תשובה it refers to. It can't be Rabbenu Yonah who preceded the Ari. It's not this one that only goes to siman 28 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20690&st=&pgnum=106 and it's not the one on orach chayim https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.30

Comment: @DoubleAA The actual reference in Yalkut Yosef is סי׳ ש, and that'd be [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.300.1?lang=bi), at the end. (And although you didn't suggest otherwise, it's worth pointing out that Yalkut Yosef explains the Peri Megadim properly.)

Comment: @magicker72 the ל then is probably referring to the teshuva ramaz mentioned there which is here https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1167&st=&pgnum=66 and like that source doesn't discuss tachanun nor friday morning at all but rather the holiness of shabbat extending into saturday night.

Comment: The Pri Megadim although he says he not sure why we do say tachanun, the Chassidim suggest that this could be a source to say that one shouldn't say tachanun. Regarding the מתן שכרן של מצות חקירה ח I count it as two sources since its two different sefarim (I don't care if its written by the same person). Shu"t shema Yisrael you should trust it since I doubled checked it and Rav Yitzchak Yosef says so! (and of course its an answer since kedushat Shabbat proves why tachanun should be said). Regarding the Sharei Teshuvah I retract.

Comment: Why would anyone trust you after clearly misrepresenting the first two (?) sources? Do you also count ever edition of the pri megadim as a separate source? It's in the back of the Friedman Shulchan Aruch, and the Bahir, and the Magen Aretz...

Comment: Why does kedushat Shabbat prove why tachanun shouldn't be said? Surely there's some source out there about the kedusha of yom tov starting thirty days before or some other extended holiday time. Do we also skip tachanun for that? What about skipping tachanun till Tuesday every week?

Comment: If any chasidim think a rabbi saying to say tachanun even though he's not sure why is a source to not say tachanun, those chasidim deserve all the criticism the early misnagdim leveled against them.

Comment: Here we go https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134420/759 a source that there's some extra neshama on sunday. So **obviously** we shouldn't say tachanun on sunday either (and thousands of years of jews were all mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Mesechta Tanis daf 27B
we don't do a fast day on Sunday
due to the nazarites 
so that might be a reason for not
saying tachnun
Maybe!!!

Comment: You should go into more detail about this.