# Why does the opening משנה in מסכת מגילה have a weird לשון?

Tags: talmud-gemara, words, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

The opening Mishna in Masechta Megilla reads as follows:

> מְגִילָּה נִקְרֵאת בְּאַחַד עָשָׂר, בִּשְׁנֵים עָשָׂר, בִּשְׁלֹשָׁה
> עָשָׂר, בְּאַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר, בַּחֲמִשָּׁה עָשָׂר. לֹא פָּחוֹת, וְלֹא
> יוֹתֵר. כְּרַכִּין הַמּוּקָּפִין חוֹמָה מִימוֹת יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בִּן נוּן —
> קוֹרִין בַּחֲמִשָּׁה עָשָׂר, כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָירוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת —
> קוֹרִין בְּאַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר, אֶלָּא שֶׁהַכְּפָרִים מַקְדִּימִין
> לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה.
>
> כֵּיצַד. חָל לִהְיוֹת יוֹם אַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר בַּשֵּׁנִי, כְּפָרִים
> וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה
> לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת בַּשְּׁלִישִׁי אוֹ בָּרְבִיעִי, כְּפָרִים
> מַקְדִּימִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת קוֹרִין בּוֹ
> בַיּוֹם, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת בָּחֲמִישִׁי,
> כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם, וּמֻקָּפוֹת
> חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת עֶרֶב שַׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים מַקְדִּימִין
> לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה, וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה קוֹרִין
> בּוֹ בַיּוֹם. חָל לִהְיוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת
> מַקְדִּימִין וְקוֹרִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר.
> חָל לִהְיוֹת אַחַר הַשַּׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים מַקְדִּימִין לְיוֹם
> הַכְּנִיסָה, וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם, וּמֻקָּפוֹת
> חוֹמָה לְמָחָר:
>
> Translation: The Megilla is read on the eleventh, on the twelfth, on
> the thirteenth, on the fourteenth, or on the fifteenth of the month of
> Adar, not earlier and not later. The mishna explains the circumstances
> when the Megilla is read on each of these days. Cities [kerakin] that
> have been surrounded by a wall since the days of Joshua, son of Nun,
> read the Megilla on the fifteenth of Adar, whereas villages and large
> towns that have not been walled since the days of Joshua, son of Nun,
> read it on the fourteenth. However, the Sages instituted that the
> villages may advance their reading to the day of assembly, i.e.,
> Monday or Thursday, when the rabbinical courts are in session and the
> Torah is read publicly, and the villagers therefore come to the larger
> towns. How so? If the fourteenth of Adar occurs on Monday, the
> villages and large towns read it on that day, and the walled cities
> read it on the next day, the fifteenth. If the fourteenth occurs on
> Tuesday or Wednesday, the villages advance their reading to the day of
> assembly, i.e., Monday, the twelfth or thirteenth of Adar; the large
> towns read it on that day, i.e., the fourteenth of Adar, and the
> walled cities read it on the next day, the fifteenth. If the
> fourteenth occurs on Thursday, the villages and large towns read it on
> that day, the fourteenth, and the walled cities read it on the next
> day, the fifteenth. If the fourteenth occurs on Shabbat eve, the
> villages advance their reading to the day of assembly, i.e., Thursday,
> the thirteenth of Adar; and the large towns and the walled cities read
> it on that day, i.e., the fourteenth of Adar. Even the walled cities
> read the Megilla on the fourteenth rather than on the fifteenth, as
> they do not read it on Shabbat. If the fourteenth occurs on Shabbat,
> both the villages and large towns advance their reading to the day of
> assembly, i.e., Thursday, the twelfth of Adar; and the walled cities
> read it on the day after Purim, the fifteenth. If the fourteenth
> occurs on Sunday, the villages advance their reading to the day of
> assembly, i.e., Thursday, the eleventh of Adar; and the large towns
> read it on that day, i.e., the fourteenth of Adar; and the walled
> cities read it on the next day, the fifteenth.

**Question**: Why by שבת does the משנה say "מקדימין וקורין but by all the other days it just says "מקדימין"

Comment: Why are you doing this

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @VeryCuriousJew I think shmosel is talking about you deleting the exact same question from about a day ago, then reposting it here (to circumvent it's closure?), rather than fixing the original question, and getting it reopened.

Comment: @VeryCuriousJew You should [have] read "[What does it mean if a question is 'closed'?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" and "[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)" in [Mi Yodeya's Help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I'll just note that the closed question was actually different to this, even though it's on the same mishna

Comment: @RabbiKaii No. there **still is** a diffent question on the same Mishnah: "[Why does the Mishna refer to Sunday as "after Shabbat"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/134419/1368)". This question is a duplicate of another question. It was also about "מקדימין _וקורין_" said only regarding שבת. There I brought, in comments, two editions of the Mishnah, the Munich manuscript no. 95 of the Talmud, as well as many others, that don't have 'וקורין' there. ...

Comment: @RabbiKaii ... I still have in my inbox a message from the OP (from 16 hours ago) thanking me for my "answers". The [link for that comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134421/question-on-the-%d7%9c%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9f-of-the-first-%d7%9e%d7%a9%d7%a0%d7%94-in-%d7%9e%d7%92%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%94?noredirect=1#comment447069_134421) goes nowhere.

Comment: It should be noted that the translation you bring gives "_advance their reading to the day of assembly_" by שבת, just like it dose by all the other days (5 times in total). So, this translation doesn't seem to make the distinction you're making between "מקדימין וקורין" and just "מקדימין".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the 'וקורין' in "חל להיות בשבת כפרים ועיירות גדולות מקדימין **וקורין** ליום הכניסה" is a copyist's/editor's error.

First, it doesn't fit grammatically: To be understood as saying "when it falls on a *Shabbat*, villages and large towns advance and read **on** the day of assembly", it should have said "חל להיות בשבת כפרים ועיירות גדולות מקדימין וקורין **ב**יום הכניסה" (instead of "**ל**יום הכניסה"). This is supported by the rest of the text, that says (when using 'קורין') "קורין **ב**ו **ב**יום", and precedes '**ל**יום הכניסה' with 'מקדימין' alone:

> חָל לִהְיוֹת יוֹם אַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר בַּשֵּׁנִי, כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת **קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם**, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת בַּשְּׁלִישִׁי אוֹ בָּרְבִיעִי, כְּפָרִים **מַקְדִּימִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה** וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת **קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם**, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת בָּחֲמִישִׁי, כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת **קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם**, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת עֶרֶב שַׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים **מַקְדִּימִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה**, וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה **קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם**. חָל לִהְיוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת מַקְדִּימִין וְקוֹרִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר. חָל לִהְיוֹת אַחַר הַשַּׁבָּת, כְּפָרִים **מַקְדִּימִין לְיוֹם הַכְּנִיסָה**, וַעֲיָרוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת **קוֹרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם**, וּמֻקָּפוֹת חוֹמָה לְמָחָר

Also, to have 'וקורין' in "חל להיות בשבת כפרים ועיירות גדולות מקדימין *וקורין* ליום הכניסה", would make it translate as "when it falls on a *Shabbat*, villages and large towns advance and read **to** the day of assembly", which make it sounds awkward in English, as well.

Beyond that, 'וקורין' doesn't appear in [Mechon Mamre's edition of the *Mishnah* of *Megillah*](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h2a.htm) (based on the manuscript attributed to Rambam), nor in [Manuscript 50 of David Kaufmann's collection](http://kaufmann.mtak.hu/en/ms50/ms50-080r.htm) (starting on the 10th line from the top of the right column, in the link). [*Mishnayot Zekher Chanokh* for *Moed* II](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37942&pgnum=284), in it's "שינויי נוסחאות", says:

> **מקדימין (וקורין)**. במשדנו"פ ובכי"ק ובכל הכ"י ובמשבי"ר ליתא

In my translation:

> **[They] advance (and read)**. In the [Naples](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44967&pgnum=201) and Pesaro editions, in the Cambridge manuscript and all [other] manuscripts, and in the [*Mishnah* that is in [the Venice edition of] the Jerusalem Talmud](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45298&pgnum=267), it isn't [to be found].

[*Dikdukei Soferim* on *Megillah*](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38519&pgnum=17), which mainly compares the Vilna edition of the Babylonian Talmud to the [Munich manuscript no. 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Codex_Hebraica_95), says:

> מקדימין (וקורין) ליום הכניסה: ליתא:

In my translation:

> [they] advance (and read) to the day of assembly: [it isn't [in the Munich manuscript]](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00003409/images/index.html?id=00003409&seite=238)

In the footnotes, he adds:

> וכן ליתא בכל הכ"י ובמשניות נאפולי ופיזרו ובירושלמי וברי"ף וברא"ש וכי היכי דליתא בכל המשנה
>
> And so it isn't [found] in all the manuscripts, nor in [the early print editions of] the *Mishnah* of Naples or Pesaro, nor in the Jerusalem Talmud, nor [in the Rif](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46673&pgnum=3), nor in the Rosh, and it [= this formulation?] is not in all [the rest of] the *Mishnah*.

Comment: but why does it not say "מקדימין וקורין" by other days. There, it just says "מקדימין"?

Comment: @VeryCuriousJew My answer is arguing that 'וקורין' got in there _by mistake_ (and hadn't always been there). Are you asking why it didn't get in _by mistake_ by other days?

Comment: yes. sorry, for not making that clear?

Comment: @VeryCuriousJew Well, Shabbat is the only place there that doesn't have 'קורין' said by it (according to the examples I bring in my answer), and it is one of only two places where 'קורין' isn't said right after "ועיירות גדולות". So, it would feel like it should be there.