# Vishnitz Minhagim

Tags: minhag, tefilin, nuschaot

Recently I found out that before the war, my grandfather was in the court of the Vishnitz Chassidim. Naturally I now want to find out what some of the Vishnitz minhagim are such as:

- What Nusach is used?
- Which opinions are followed for Tefilin?
- Regular Ashkenaz Tallis or special version?
- Other Minhagim

Would appreciate if anyone has information or can direct me to any resources.

Comment: hat with a knot on the left side of the ribbon.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily be so quick to switch.after all, his grandfather, or his grandfather was probably not hassidic.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Vizhnitz today is not one, but three distinct *Chassidus'n*, each with slightly different *minhagim*. There are various dedicated *Vizhnitzer siddurim* which bring the main *minhagim*. Any major Judaica store should be able to help you get one. The siddur may not specify *Tefillin* and *Tallis* type (what is that even?), and anyway the *minhagim* of a *Chassidus* are numerous to list in a Stack Exchange post. See e.g. about [Tachanun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35099/3073).

Specific *Vizhnitzer minhagim* off the top of my head:

- Dip thrice in salt on *Shabbos*
- Special "flat" *Shabbos davenen/kiddush nigunim*
- *Mincha* before *sh'kia* even outside *Eretz Yisrael*
- Dancing around the *bimah* by last half of *L'cha dodi*

**Source:** I worked for – and was very close with – one of the *Vizhnitzer Chassidus'n* for three years.