# Better less with kavannah than more without?

Tags: tefilla, kavana-concentration, kavana-intent

Right at the beginning of the Tur and [Shulchan Aruch, siman 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it says that it is better to pray a little with kavannah (proper concentration?) than more without. I don't know that anyone argues. I also don't see it put into practice in many places where I might have applied it.
The Rambam ([Hil. Tefillah 4(14)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.4.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says pretty clearly that we should not daven at all without kavannah, and if we did, go back and pray again. But, later authorities seem to tone it down - after all, we don't have so much kavannah anyhow.
That is pretty much the answer I have gotten when I asked, say: I'm really tired. Maybe I should sleep instead of going to shul for maariv, and hope I get up in time to daven later. No, no! Go to shul now and do the best you can.
Maybe I should say less of Pesukei D'zimrah? No, no! Birkas Krias Shema - are you nuts?
Anyhow, when Slichos comes around I really struggle. Do I have kavannah for more, or am I just stretching the kavannah I have much thinner? By the time I get to Hodu I'm frequently exhausted [I do have health issues with fatigue]. What should one do? "*How* can you think of skipping prayers at a critical time like the Aseres Yemei Teshuvah?!"
Also, what if a person can follow with the words, and pays attention, but is past the point of *enjoying* what's happening? He might have felt more *inspired* if he had said less. Does that play a role?
I'm asking for sources for practical rulings, but also advice on the right attitude.

Update: On re-reading, I don't want the impression that the question is based on my physical situation, as if I'm tired all the time. The real question is more based on a *mental* weariness, on one's ability to "hold kop", the point where one feels prayers turning into mechanical reading without really paying attention.
Update: tesvov has suggested in a number of comments that the principle stated by the Tur *only* applies to optional additions, like the Tikkun Chatzos that is the topic where he states it. Interesting suggestion - obviously Rav Avigdor Miller quoted below disagrees - and it would be good to have an explicit statement by a posek about it.  [[Berachos 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.34a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) might be a good source on this, but of course in those days prayers were more fluid.]
Third update: My son-in-law suggested what may be a compromise position, though personally I find it rather a depressing one: The requirement for kavannah is indeed absolute, and according to the [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.4.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) one should perhaps never say any part of the davening, even the Amidah, without proper kavannah. *However*, since in our times we don't have so much kavannah anyhow, this no longer serves as an excuse to skip anything.

You really have to see the wording of the Rambam there - not really quoted by later poskim, but super-powerful and perfectly clear [ital. mine].

> Any prayer uttered without mental concentration *is not prayer*. If a service has been recited without such concentration, it must be recited again devoutly. A person finds that his thoughts are confused and his mind is
> distracted: He is *forbidden to pray* till he has recovered his mental
> composure. Hence, on returning from a journey or if one is weary or
> distressed, it is forbidden to pray till his mind is composed. The
> sages said that *he should wait three days* till he is rested and his
> mind is calm, and then he recites the prayers...

I wonder if the much less sharp language of the poskim in [OH 98](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.98.1?lang=bi) is evidence to the contrary: These more recent poskim seem to say instead that *you really really need* to have kavannah, but... let's talk about whether you have to pray again if you pray without. I'm not seeing a nice clear, Don't pray. Still, might that be the logical conclusion?

Further update: [Reflections on Yomim Noraim davening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DwAVyvl5MIEwj8I6jzKFNsEvOCWom5lX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are these answers to שאלות you're getting? "No, no!" and "are you nuts?"? There is plenty of wiggle room (or dancing room, really) in omitting customary-but-not-obligatory parts of our daily prayer, especially for good reason.

Comment: I think they were answers. And did I really list any "non-obligatory" parts of the tefillah? Korbonos? Ani Maamin? Extra tehillim? You can skip peskukei d'zimrah if you're late, but no one has told me yet to be late because I think I'll daven better without.

Comment: "I don't know that anyone argues" - R. Hutner was known to say, טוב מעט בלא כונה מהרבה בלא כונה

Comment: If given free reign, many people would underestimate their ability to perform at prayer and skip too much. The people pressuring you to show up are making sure that the middle ground you end up at doesn't sell yourself short.

Comment: Worth noting as well that the question of what the tzibbur skips is different from what individuals may skip.

Comment: Rambam also rules (Hilchot Tefilla 5:2) that one is not allowed to pray if hungry, so one must eat before praying in the morning. However, this logic is not extended to being tired! Perhaps this is due to the concern outlined by Double AA above?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129576/discussion-on-question-by-michoelr-better-less-with-kavannah-than-more-without).

Comment: @MichoelR "no one has told me yet to be late because I think I'll daven better without [peskukei d'zimrah]" If coming at the published start time doesn't leave you enough time to say everything at your pace, then telling you to come at that start time is effectively equivalent to telling you to come late.

Comment: This question is based on wrong attribution and wrong translation of Siman 1 in Shulchan Aruch. Misattribution - the section you are quoting is discussing tikun chatzos only. Among other things Kitzur 1:5 explains that pretty clearly. Mistranslation - you are mistranslating word "tachanunim." It doesn't mean prayers, it means supplications which are not a set part of any ordained prayers to begin with. Therefore, the entire question is based on flawed premises.

Comment: @Tesvov I don't see that the Kitzur is doing more than simply quoting that part of the Tur, in order. As with all your comments on this, I am hearing your point of view (which is definitely interesting and possible) but no attempt to bring sources to justify it. That is against the whole point of this website, where people seek information based on sources.

Comment: As for תחנונים, see Brochos 28b and 29b. It is a required part of tefillah.

Comment: @Tesvov I'm adding your suggestion into the original post.

Comment: @Tesvov I'm concerned that tesvov's answer was deleted. I think it went too far, but it provided a necessary counterpoint to the other three answers posted. My _guess_ is that it was closer to a lot of people's positions than the answers that remain. tesvov, come back!

Comment: @MichoelR - I deleted my answer because I realized that the question is based on an incorrect premise. The question is also too long for me to edit.

Comment: @MichoelR - you probably meant to ask something like: "I am only able to concentrate for a limited amount of time. What prayers should I use this time for and what prayers should I skip?"

Comment: @Tesvov Yes, that might be my question. But as I mentioned, it's not just for me, it's a practical question for lots of others as well. Without speaking for anyone else, if a person found that he just said most of Shacharis without paying much attention, should he (a) try for a little more kavannah next time, or (b) realize that he's doing it all wrong and skip most of what he said so he can pay more attention to what's left, or (c) ? I don't think I'm unique; I think most people have tabled the question a while ago.

Comment: Kitzur 14:7 may be helpful :
"לֹא יוּכַל לְהִתְפַּלֵּל שְׁמוֹנֶה עֶשְׂרֵה עִם הַצִּבּוּר אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן יְמַהֵר, טוֹב לוֹ יוֹתֵר לְהִתְפַּלֵּל בִּפְנֵי עַצְמוֹ כַּסֵּדֶר בִּמְתִינוּת וּבְכַוָּנָה"
"If you will not manage to begin Shmoneh Esrei together with a minyan unless you rush, it is better to pray individually in the established order slowly and with concentration."

Comment: @Tesvov It _might_ be helpful. But the conclusion might be, everyone should stop going to minyan! I don't think the Ba'al HaKitzur had that in mind. It sounds like he's dealing with a specific case where the person came late enough to minyan so that keeping up is impossible with any kavanah. I don't know how to draw conclusions from it for a normal baal habos and a regular minyan.

Comment: @MichoelR - my conclusion would be is to gradually train yourself to say all customary prayers with the level of kavanah that you're comfortable with.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2656/759

Answer (score 1):

A related question was the topic of an episode of "Dimensions of the Daf."  Rambam in one place (which I think is your citation) says about the Amidah that if you did not have kavanah, you must start again. But elsewhere he says that if one had kavanah at the beginning but not in the middle of the Amidah then you don't restart.

The explanation given (in the episode) is that there are two sorts of kavanah.  The first is that without the kavanah that you are engaging in a conversation before hakadosh baruch hu, you aren't praying at all; so without that appreciation in mind, you haven't started the Amidah and must daven "in the first place."  The second sort is an understanding of the words you are saying and their implications (as opposed to just saying them from habit).  It is this second sort of kavanah that the Rambam says if you had it at the start (of the Amidah) you need not repeat the prayer (which of course would not even have been a prayer in the first place if you didn't have kavanah that you are addressing hashem).

Comment: Thank you. I believe your answer is from R' Chaim Brisker, though I don't have the reference in front of me. _And_ I believe I heard that the Chazon Ish gave a different answer (though I don't have the reference in front of me!)

Comment: This is the famous first piece in Chiddushei R' Chaim on the Rambam. Not sure it answers the question though.

Comment: @DoubleAA this is not the famous first piece in Chiddushei R. Chaim on the Rambam. Might be the second though

Comment: Turns out it's Hilchot Tefillah 4:1. Second piece in the book after Yesodei haTorah 5:1

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my best impression of the answer to my question, taking into account what I've heard so far. I am still sorely lacking in poskim who deal with this directly.

1. The Rambam quoted is pretty clear. Prayer without kavannah doesn't exist and is actually not allowed. [One might restrict the latter to the Amidah; perhaps its special status means that it's sacrilege to devalue it.]
2. The Tur quoted is also pretty clear: It is better to skip prayers rather than say them without kavannah. *However*, he says what he says in a section on Tikkun Chatzos and it may therefore apply only to voluntary prayers, לפנים משורת הדין. I'll clarify that shortly בע"ה.
3. Many people I've asked have responded pretty sharply [as usual without clear sources]: You cannot use this as an excuse to skip all your prayers. What is in the siddur's prayer service, or - at least - whatever we can determine is from the Anshei Knesses Hagedolah, you ought to be saying. It's a terrible slippery slope to start skipping half the davening.

So let me bring an idea I once heard from R' Tzvi Berkowitz shlit"a. He called it "blackmailing Hashem". Say A is required, B and C are not acceptable. Someone might say, Well, you should be happy I did B, because I might have done C which is even worse!
-You should be happy I only said *some* of the prayers, but with kavannah, because I might have just bopped through all of them fast without any kavannah at all, like so many other people.
-You should be happy I said the prayers at least, even if I paid zero attention, because so many other people skip and don't say all of them or even any of them.
You can't do either one. There are set prayers, and you must say them with proper concentration and kavannah.
Of course, if you really can't, then that Rambam and the Shulchan Aruch suggest alternatives. You're late for the minyan and can't say all of them properly, skip these and then these. Optional additions, the Tur says it's better only to say what you can say properly. You just came from a journey and can't think straight - don't pray till you can!
But one needs to be erlich and there's a reason the Rambam gave a case of coming from a difficult journey. It probably isn't a proper excuse that you aren't in the mood right now.

On the "slippery slope" argument quoted above, I would add that the slippery slope runs both ways, and I think we might be pretty far down the other way! I'm not sure that the average person davening knows that if he is just rattling off the words without kavannah, he needs to stop doing that and do something else. Could be he heard enough times, "Well, what are you going to do - not daven?" that he thinks this is fine b'dieved, and he'll work on it when he's older.

After all this, I need to point out that I did not say a word about what "kavannah" means exactly. See that Rambam further on, see the R' Chaim, see the poskim. That is an important part of the issue, of course. I don't mean to suggest that something isn't good enough if it really is. And, it would be a further discussion how to choose tradeoffs between different *levels* of kavannah.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but it's worth mentioning here for any readers. I have a Rambam "Siddur" that has every prayer needed for every Jewish event and it all fits into one book. But if you hand this siddur to an average Jew today they will marvel at all the prayers that are "missing." However, the reality is that most of the prayers that we take for granted as being necessary are often recent additions and aren't really required. Even such "standard prayers" like Modeh Ani weren't considered essential even in the time of the Shulchan Arukh. Rambam's son famously complained that people didn't have the proper Kawwanah for the Amidah (required prayer) because they were up all night doing dirges/selihot which aren't required at all.

Based on this I've advised friends who struggle with having enough Kawwanah for prayers to spend time finding out what prayers are actually required vs recent additions/recommendations. Because it's certainly possible that they (or you) have enough proper concentration for the required prayers, but maybe not for all the additions that fill many siddurs nowadays.

When praying alone I use the Rambam siddur or a similar Yemenite siddur so that way I can focus on my prayer and not have to spend mental energy filtering everything else out. I reserve my Sephardic and Ashkenazic siddurs to be used when I'm at synagogue.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is very much an answer to my question, but I'd like to to hear more about what poskim say on the topic. Also, do you have the reference to that quote from the Rambam's son?

Comment: @MichoelR I haven't heard any Rav tackle the question of ignoring non required prayers to focus on only those required, because then they'd be caught in a catch 22 where some may accuse them of telling people to not pray as much, or stuff like that. I'll search for the quote but it's in Abraham benHaRambam's book the Guide to Serving God.

Comment: Is there a breakdown of what is and what is not essential without going through the entire Torah?

Comment: @IsraelB. I recommend getting a Rambam siddur so you can see for yourself. There are also lots of explanatory notes. Warning the entire siddur is in Hebrew https://seforimcenter.com/Siddur-ha-Rambam---Nusach-Teiman__p-13750.aspx

Comment: @Aaron You know it already, but it's worth mentioning that there is sort of a "Rambam siddur" in his Sefer Avodah, Hilchos Tefilah u'Nesias Kapaim, basically him just quoting all the prayers. It would be hard to use in practice, lot of jumping around and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

while all parts of prayer should have kavana there are some parts that require kavana in order to fulfill your obligation in saying them. The parts that come to mind are the pasuk "poseach es yadecha" in ashre, the first two paskim in shema, and the first the brachos in the amida. (sources needed)

One technique for having greater kavana during davening is one that doesn't require any skipping. Each day taking some time to focus more on a different section of the siddur during shachris, mincha, maariv and this way by the end of the year you have said all of davening many times with your best kavana.

Of course it would be great in theory to just be on the level where all of your prayer all of the time would be like this but what Hashem wants from us is to put forth our best efforts as prayer is defined as "service of the heart" (meseches taanis 2a). "the Merciful One desires the heart" (I think the zohar). Also in regards to making our effort when we do a little Hashem will help us out a lot as it says in Meseches Yoma 39a before the hadran, "if he will mekadesh himself a little bit then he will be mekashin harbe."

Comment: Thank you, Dude. Note, though, that my question was: When should we *skip prayers* in order to have more kavannah on what's left? That is, after all, what the Tur is telling us to do. Are you answering that we should just say all the rest however?

Comment: I'm suggesting one method of working on having kavana while you daven that doesn't have you skip anything but to work on having it a little bit at a time

Comment: I understand. But it involves saying all the other prayers without kavannah in the meantime. Is the Tur not saying that we should rather say less of them, if that helps? In other words, why is your starting point not skipping anything, instead of a starting point more like this: Say what you can say with kavannah, and gradually add prayers if you can say them with kavannah as well?

Comment: I just don't understand skipping anything. The siddur is made the way it is for a reason. The tefilos were not designed to be skipped over just bc some have more importance than others.

Comment: Yeah, but, according to the Tur: "I just don't understand saying a prayer without kavannah." According to the Rambam: "Any prayer uttered without kavannah is not prayer." You are skipping them.

Comment: 1. There are levels of kavana and the general one is to have in mind that all of my prayers will be accepted as if I had said them with every kavana. 2. We aren't perfect but we should make an effort with emes. For someone on their level it might mean skipping. On the other hand every part of the siddur is there for a reason to be said.

Comment: I think I'm still waiting to hear how you read the Rambam and the Tur. There are "levels of kavana", but the Rambam and the Tur must have _some_ level in mind when they say it's assur to daven in that state, or that you should say less rather than pray in that state. What is the situation where you would tell someone that?

Comment: A person should have as much kavana as they are able to on their level. Pesuki d'zimra for example was instituted to help someone develop kavana before and the brachos of shema as well. I don't believe the rambam or the tur would agree with nullifying the Amidah bc someone else didn't think they had enough kavana. The Amidah is what tefillah is in halacha by the way. Not only that but the purpose of the beginning of prayers is to focus on getting kavana so skipping that bc you don't have kavana makes no sense at all.

Comment: "I don't believe the rambam or the tur would agree with nullifying the Amidah bc someone else didn't think they had enough kavana." Even though they said it? The Rambam calls it, assur. You can't tell me what "you believe" in such a discussion.

Comment: Bc you're using the words of the rambam as an excuse without acknowledging what they mean. You have an obligation to pray. Your obligation for kavana is to have as much as you are capable which can at minimum be I am praying to fulfill my obligation. The rambam did not write these words to cancel anything that chachamim instituted or anything in the siddur.

Comment: It would be good if you would provide any kind of source for these things. So far you have just claimed that whatever the Rambam said, you will never really apply it. The Rambam is not cancelling anything; he is telling you when it applies and when not. - But it sounds like we don't have more to discuss here, unless you have a source.

Comment: davening is the norm. doing something outside of the norm is what requires an explicit source. all you have done is twist the Rambam's words into an excuse for not davening.

Answer (score -1):

Wow. Just saw this over Yom Tov. *[Rav Avigdor Miller on Tefillah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1607633442)*, just published (2021), by R' Yaakov Astor, quotes from his shiurim. [He says in the introduction that some of the quotes were lightly edited. I couldn't tell which shiur exactly it came from.] Anyhow, p. 127:

> Question: In P'sukei D'zimrah there are so many selections from
> Tehilim, and the Rav has told us that every word is a gem and an
> opportunity for perfection of the mind. But can one really concentrate
> on so many verses and so many different thoughts?

> Answer: Certainly
> not. And therefore, you shouldn't even try to say everything. Just
> to rattle off words and not gain any da'as, is worthless. It's not
> completely worthless, but it's just about worthless.
> Instead, take
> your time. "Tov ma'at tachanunum b'kavanah m'harbeh b'li kavanah -
> Better to daven a small amount with concentration, than to daven a lot
> without concentration. Say a little, but think about what you're
> saying. Study the words and understand what you're saying. That's the
> real achievement in davening.
> Now, of course, if you have a great
> deal of time, you can start davening three hours before the tzibbur,
> and you'll be able to do justice to a good part of the P'sukei
> D'zimrah. But whatever it is, you should spend time using your head in
> davening, not just your lips.

"You shouldn't even *try* to say everything."
Too bad they didn't ask him about other parts of tefillah, though.

Counterpoint: A very choshuv yunger man mentioned to me what Rav Shach z"l wrote in his haskamah to R' Meyer Birnbaum's *Darchei Hatefillah* : [paraphrased] "Use this for studying about prayer, but don't use it while you pray." You aren't *supposed* to be studying prayer while you pray, you're supposed to be talking to Hashem.
That would seem to go against at least the "three hours" part of what Rav Miller said, and perhaps the whole idea of "gems" and "so many different thoughts". The words of P'sukei D'zimrah are indeed gems, but that doesn't mean you should spend time examining all the facets while you pray.
I don't think that would contradict a middle ground, where someone might skip part of the davening in order to do a decent job with the rest.

Comment: Almost all of the material in similar publications is based on recordings of Rav Miller's talks delivered to people Rav Miller knew personally. Therefore, it is very likely that the above advice from Rav Miller (as well as other advice based on his tapes and recordings) was tailored and limited to a specific individual, demographic, or age-range only.

Comment: In addition, טוב מעט תחנונים בכוונה מהרבות בלא כוונה is a quote from Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 1:4, which discusses tikkun chatzot - a prayer which is not obligatory to begin with.

Comment: @Tesvov Not sure, but I think from the introduction to the book that these are generally from the Thursday night shiurim (which are also on the tapes that most people get), which always ended with "Questions on any topic!" I often used to go to them; there were like a hundred or two people there, from everywhere. Farthest thing from "tailored" that is possible.

Comment: @Tesvov - _that_ is what I have been asking in this whole post. Do you have any evidence that the quote only applies there? _I_ thought it was at the beginning of Orach Chaim, because it's with things like "shivisi Hashem l'negdi tamid", and applies to _everything_. So far no one has posted here a single posek, except maybe Rabbi Miller z"l.

Comment: @Tesvov Plus, Rav Miller used to make it very clear at the talks that he expected many more people to hear them. For instance, he would ask at the beginning that if you needed to cough, get up quietly and go outside to do it; he didn't want it on the tape.

Comment: @Tesvov Of course, Rav Miller is going to represent the "musar school" side of things. I'd be happy to hear from a source that represents the more "just do what it says" school; that's what I asked for! If you have any sources?