# Is it better to daven with no kavanah or just not daven at all?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer, kavana-concentration

I thought I read that some say that davening without kavanah may be even worse than simply not davening. Is this true?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126158/better-less-with-kavannah-than-more-without/127451#127451